# Material angular virtual repeat not showing values in drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to setup an infinite repeat for a drop-down selection as the user keep scrolling.

Using $http tried something along these lines. But can't seem to get it working.

```
   $scope.infiniteItems = {
           numLoaded_: 0,
           toLoad_: 0,
           items: [],

           // Required.
           getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
               if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                   this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                   return null;
               }
               return this.items[index];
           },

           // Required.
           getLength: function () {
               return this.numLoaded_ + 25;
           },

           fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
               if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                   this.toLoad_ += 10;
                   AssemblyJigsFactory.getData().then(angular.bind(this, function (obj) {
                       this.items = this.items.concat(obj.data.success.data);
                       this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                   }));
               }
           }
       };
```

If I `console.log( $scope.infiniteItems);` it comes up empty,

```
Object {numLoaded_: 0, toLoad_: 0, items: Array[0]}
```

My HTML is a simple dialog pops up with this mark-up

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                                    <label>Storage Location</label>
                                    <md-select  ng-model="newJig.storagelocation" placeholder="Storage Location"  ng-cloak>
                                        <md-option>
                                          <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
                                            <div md-virtual-repeat="item in infiniteItems"  md-on-demand class="repeated-item" flex>
                                              {{item.name}}
                                            </div>
                                          </md-virtual-repeat-container>
                                          </md-option>
                                        <div ng-hide="allItems.length">No items found</div>
                                    </md-select>
                                </md-input-container>
```

But `storage location` is just not showing any values. I am not sure whether the html setup is right either.

I have tested this

```
 AssemblyJigsFactory.getData().then(function(res){

console.log( res.data.success);
});
```

on its own and data keeps coming in.

```
Object {total: 50, per_page: 25, current_page: 1, ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, change your `md-input-container` as follows.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
     <label>Storage Location</label>
     <md-select  ng-model="newJig.storagelocation" placeholder="Storage Location"  ng-cloak>
         <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
             <div md-virtual-repeat="item in infiniteItems"  md-on-demand class="repeated-item" flex>
                 <md-option ng-value='item.value'>{{item.name}}
                 </md-option>
            </div>
         </md-virtual-repeat-container>                                                         
     <div ng-hide="allItems.length">No items found</div>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Hope this can help.